# Why $k((x,t))$ can not be a local field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, local-fields

If $k$ is a finite field, then $k((x))$ is a local field, and we can define a discrete valuation on $k((x))$ with respect to which it is complete. It is sometimes called a 1-dimensional local field.

I am interested in knowing if there are proper generalisations of $k((x))$ in several variables preserving the localness.

For example, I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_local_field) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.0586.pdf), there is a 2-dimensional local field $k((x))((t))$, which is the field of Laurent series in the variable $t$ over the 1-dimensional local field $k((x))$.

- If it is a local field, then what is the valuation? Is it the same valuation as $k((x))$?

More generally, consider the field $k((x,t))$ of the Laurent power series in $x,t$. There are no results claiming it is a local field. To be a local field, there must be a discrete valuation on $k((x,t))$.

I need to understand if $k((x,t))$ can not be a local field, or, we just don't know yet if there is a discrete valuation making $k((x,t))$ a local field. Can someone clarify it please?

Comment: I think that you are confused (understandably) by the fact that "2-dimensional local fields" are not local fields.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie, ok, so there is no discrete valuation on $k((x))((t))$. Right? same on $k((x,t))$

Comment: Of course there are discrete valuations, namely there are discrete valuations on $L((t))$ for every field $L$. The point is that for $L=k((x))$, this makes $k((x))$ a bounded subfield.

Comment: @YCor, Can you discuss it in an answer because I didn't understand the concept of "bounded subfield"? All we need to do is define a discrete valuation that makes it a complete field. What is the problem here in this case?

Comment: @MAS a valuation defines a distance $d(x,y)=\exp(-v(x-y))$. Bounded means bounded in this metric; for a subring it just means that the valuation takes values $\ge 0$. For every field $L$, $L((x))$ is naturally a complete field for the discrete valuation wrt $x$.

Comment: @YCor, well thank you for the explanation. If $k((x))((t))$ is complete with respect to a discrete valuation then what is the problem calling it a local field just like $k((x))$? Because this is the definition of local field.

Comment: @MAS I think that "local field" sometimes assume that the topology is locally compact (which for $k((t))$ is true iff $k$ is finite). Of course these fields are of interest even when $k$ is infinite. However the topology for which $k((x))$ is bounded is or is not useful, depending on the context. Note that $k((x))((t))$ is not symmetric in $x,t$: for instance $\sum_{n\ge 0} x^{-n}t^n$ makes sense in it, while it is ill-defined in $k((t))((x))$. So the notation $k((x,t))$ can be confusing, or referring to something else.

Comment: @YCor, yes, now I understand it. Locally compactness is losing here. Can you give any hints why $k((x,t)) \not\cong k((x))((t))$?

Comment: @MAS I already gave a hint.

Comment: @YCor, how? We have to show that they can not be isomorphic as topological spaces and, hence, can not be isomorphic as fields. But how do I know their respective valuation can not give same topologies?

Comment: @MAS Sure. My hint is that they're not "canonically equal", I agree that it doesn't prove they're not isomorphic. But I'm not sure what $k((x,t))$ means. Is it just the field of fractions of $k[[x,t]]$?

Comment: @YCor, yes $k((x,t))$ is just the field of fraction of $k[[x,t]]$